# Can Xero assets be modified using the Xero-Python API?

Tags: xero-api

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently engaged in a project that involves updating Xero assets through the python-xero API. Despite my testing efforts, I have been unable to achieve this successfully. It appears that updating a draft asset should be possible based on my understanding.

def xero_create_asset(viper_asset):
asset_api = AssetApi(api_client)
xero_tenant_id = get_xero_tenant_id()

```
serial_number = 'serial_number'
xero_id = 'xero_id'
asset_name = 'Test'


asset = Asset(asset_id=xero_id,
              asset_name=asset_name, 
              asset_number = viper_asset['asset_id'],
              serial_number = serial_number)

# api_response = asset_api.create_asset(xero_tenant_id, asset)
api_akt = asset_api.create_asset
print(api_response)
return api_response
```

[Xero API history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDVZV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the status field otherwise you will get the 403 forbidden error. You also need to include the asset number to avoid an error 400.

Comment: Thank you worked for me. Simplay added the asset_status = AssetStatus.DRAFT

asset = Asset(asset_id=xero_id,
              asset_name=asset_name, 
              asset_number = viper_asset['asset_id'],
              serial_number = serial_number,
              asset_status = AssetStatus.DRAFT
)